# Is passing stringified object as prop in React component better than plain JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just my concern, I know when the props changed, the component will be re-rendered.
React can not perform deep comparison on old and new passed object to props 
so:

`{ key: 'value' }` and `{ key: 'value' }` is always different and causing re-render.

How about passing object to props like this:

`<Component smth={JSON.stringify({ key: 'value' })}/>`

It is a string so React can compare old and new effectivly ?

Comment: The answer is **no**, **you should pass the JS object**. If you want a concrete explanation you should give an actual example, it is an **anti-pattern** and you should fix the component's logics / use memoization instead.

Comment: Honestly, It just came into my mind and I have no actual example. But if it is ant-pattern, I think it should has some kind of common explanation for that.

Comment: The best practice with React is to pass only the relevant data as props, not a whole object or state. Most of the times, a whole object as a prop value comes from some data that is stored in some kind of state (local, context, redux, etc) and it isn't re-instantiated each render cycle, it's just the same object reference that is passed around. Like Dennis Vash said, memoization is a solution to computed objects/arrays, but first, measure performance before doing any unnecessary memoization as it could just complexify the apps logic with minimal perf improvements in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string is a primitive type, so `"a" == "a" //true` and yes if covert them to string by `JSON.stringify()` it won't trigger re-render as long as object structure remains the same. Btw This is an anti-pattern - you shouldn't compare the stringify versions. ( credit @DennisVash )

but object is reference type; so `{} == {} //false` but if you store the object reference and pass it to the props it won't change in renders and won't trigger re-render every time; here is a example in a functional component keeping the obj reference in a local state;

```
//!! it can be placed outside the component and wont change in recurring renders; 
//!! it will work; but definitely not recommended;
// let obj = { key: 'value'} 

function FancyComponent() {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState({ key: 'value'});

  // optionally you may store it in ref, in some special use-cases
  // const ref = useRef({ key: "value" });

  render(){
    // let obj = { key: 'value'} //!! no it won't work here credits to @EmileBergeron
    return <>
      <Component smth={obj}/>
    </>
  }
}
```

```js
console.log("a" == "a"); //true
console.log({} == {}); //false
let obj = {};
console.log(obj == {}); //false
console.log(obj == obj); //true
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a point, I took some research after posting this questions as well and your answer is great. Thanks !

Comment: For more detail, when passing ref that stored the object, React will compare the ref instead of the object itself if it is the same ref, the component will stay. When your object changes, the ref changes as well, React still compare the ref and then causing the re-render. Right ?

Comment: This is an anti-pattern - you shouldn't compare the stringify versions.

Comment: @thelonglqd yes exactly, we call it `shallow comparison`; google that for further reading

Comment: @DennisVash: Yeah, I have ever seen it before, but there is some reasons behind the scene and I want to know what it is. Can you explain why it is anti-pattern for this case ?

Comment: @DennisVash I didn't mean to encourage that behavior btw; thank you for saying that; I'll add it to the answer with your permission

Comment: The example is misleading. Storing the object in a local variable is the same thing as passing the object directly, props comparison wise.

Comment: @EmileBergeron yeahhh, that is right; we can use a `useRef` hook or store it in a `state`; is there another way too?

Comment: Anything that isn't instantiated each render cycle will use the same object ref. Redux, context, `useRef`, `useState`, `useReducer`, `useMemo`, module-scope variables, even globals (but don't), etc.

Comment: @EmileBergeron fixed the example with a state hook; 

Comment: @EmileBergeron, @Captain Mhmdrz_A: Can you guys explain more on that point ? `Storing the object in a local variable is the same thing as passing the object directly`. I don't get it :(

Comment: @thelonglqd `const obj = { p: 2 }; return <Component prop={obj} />` is the same as `<Component prop={{ p: 2 }} />`. There's absolutely no gain (other than legibility in some cases).

Comment: @thelonglqd it means we try to save the object refrence in a variable and reuse it later, but we are just creating that new variable every time and pass the new variable to the props which means a new reference in new variable hence "useless";

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thank @CaptainMhmdrz_A

Answer (score 1):

The stringified version adds extra computational overhead, so if you want to do it a lot it might slow down your website.

You could update your view manually using `this.forceUpdate()`, but if you'd use something like redux, you shouldn't need to do that most of the time. Some example `.jsx` file would help identify how to avoid hacky things like converting stuff to string.

Comment: What you pointed out is quite hard to know if we do not measure. But it is still the things We need to concern. Thanks.